# LyX Toolbar off screen

Tags: lyx, windows

Somehow my LyX standard toolbar went off screen in Windows 8 (I think it may have something to do with the full screen toggle) and I have no idea how to move it to its original position. I have attached a photo of my "minimum working example" below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a very heavy user of LyX 2.1.
[image: off screen standard toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling  > Session Handling

Uncheck "Restore window layouts and geometries" and then restart LyX.